# Does my code inside preprocessor directives included in compiled code if the directive is not present in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, preprocessor-directive

I have an application which I want to create a demo for it. I prefer to give another exe for my paid version and different one for demo to prevent people with demo version to crack my paid version. For now I have commented the code I need in demo so whenever I have to create a demo I go over these comments and make the necessary changes. Today I realize the #if directive..

Now my question is if I have a code like this

```
#if DEMO
   public string test()
   {
     return "blabla";
   }
#endif
```

and I did not define `DEMO` directive, so my code gets greyed out obviously and I can't reach this method which is what I was expecting so far. Now I have rebuild my project without defining `DEMO` directive and I deleted my .pdb file from output folder after that I tried to check my executable with dotpeek and I could not see this test method there.

Can I use this approach to separate my demo and paid version executables? Lets say this `test` method is a demo method so it wont be seen in paid version if someone cracks it. And same goes for opposite, if this `test` method is a paid version method and I put it inside `#if !DEMO` then if I define `DEMO` and rebuild my exe I won't see this `test` method there right?

As I mention before I already checked the code and could not see my methods with dotpeek but I just want to be 100% sure that these methods wont seen in programs like dotpeek or anywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code is completely omitted if the symbol isn't defined. It can be absolute garbage code - the compiler ignores it completely; it just looks for the end (either `#endif` or `#else`).

The question about whether that suits your needs for demo/paid versions is somewhat different, but the answer from the technical perspective of "what gets included in the output" is simple.

Comment: Okay thank you, if there is another good approach to separate some functionalities for my demo I would like to know them too. My approach for demo might be a wrong way but at least my demo code will always be up to date and I won't have to go over hundreds of line every time I want to release a new demo version for my application, all I have to do is define DEMO and rebuild my code.

Comment: @ShinoLex: You should stick to one question per post - and if you want to ask about how to build a demo version, you'll need to include *really, really* specific requirements, otherwise it's likely to be closed as being too broad.